# Implementing TableView Navigation xcode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Good afternoon,

I'm trying to follow the tutorial from this website: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Implementing_TableView_Navigation_using_Xcode_Storyboards to implement a TableView Navigation, but in the last step I get an error from my xcode.

I'm going to post the code where I have the error code because I'm a little desperated about that error. I hope you can help me.

**CarDetailViewController.m - 
TableViewStory**

```
    #import "CarTableViewController.h"
    #import "CarTableViewCell.h"
    #import "CarDetailViewController.h"

    @implementation CarDetailViewController
    @synthesize makeLabel = _makeLabel;
    @synthesize modelLabel = _modelLabel;
    @synthesize imageView = _imageView;
    @synthesize carDetailModel = _carDetailModel;

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        self.makeLabel.text = [self.carDetailModel objectAtIndex:0];
        self.modelLabel.text = [self.carDetailModel objectAtIndex:1];
        self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:
                                [self.carDetailModel objectAtIndex:2]];
    }

    -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
    {
        if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowCarDetails"])
        {
            CarDetailViewController *detailViewController =
            [segue destinationViewController];

            NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [self.tableView
                                        indexPathForSelectedRow];
------------PROPERTY TABLEVIEW NOT FOUND ON OBJECT OF TYPE 'CARDETAILVIEWCONTROLLER'
            detailViewController.carDetailModel = [[NSArray alloc]
                                                   initWithObjects: [self.carMakes
                                                                     objectAtIndex:[myIndexPath row]],
------------PROPERTY CARMAKES NOT FOUND ON OBJECT OF TYPE 'CARDETAILVIEWCONTROLLER'
                                                   [self.carModels objectAtIndex:[myIndexPath row]],
                                                   [self.carImages objectAtIndex:[myIndexPath row]],
                                                   nil];
        }
    }

    @end
```

**CarDetailViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface CarDetailViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *carDetailModel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *makeLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *modelLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

@end
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The reason you're getting a "property not found" error for `tableView` and `carMakes` is that there are no properties named `tableView` or `carMakes`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `prepareForSegue` you've pasted into `CarDetailViewController` comes from `CarTableViewController` in the tutorial. Presumably, that class extends `UITableViewController` (by virtue of which it has a `tableView` property) and has a custom `carMakes` property.

But that just relates to this one specific case. I think it's more important to understand what the error you got *means*, so that you can recognize how to fix it in the future. Your code was referencing properties that could not be found, because they do not exist. That's why you saw an error telling you that properties could not be found. It's actually a pretty straightforward error message.

Comment: duplicate answer of mine

Comment: Yes, we answered at basically the same time. Your answer was in a deleted state as I was typing mine out.

Answer (score 1):

`prepareForSegue` needs to go in `CarTableViewController` NOT `CarDetailViewController`

Looks like there was a part 1 of the tutorial, make sure you followed it as well:
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Using_Xcode_Storyboards_to_Build_Dynamic_TableViews_with_Prototype_Table_View_Cells